# install mysql on centos 7 failure

Tags: mysql, linux

I have problem to mysql server it to centos 7 , it pop the below message . would advise how to install mysql , or centos 7 is not allow to run mysql ? thanks

```
#yum install mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.uhost.hk
* extras: centos.uhost.hk
* updates: centos.uhost.hk
Package 1:mariadb-5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. Google for the difference, but most likely MariaDB is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In the default repositories comes bundled MariaDB (a fork of MySQL), whose operation is identical to that of MySQL and you can investigate their differences ([for example here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/)) and install it can do the following:

```
yum install mariadb-server mariadb
```

For install the MySQL in Centos 7 you can do this

```
yum install wget
wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm
```

and then:

```
yum install mysql-server
```

[SOURCE OF MYSQL](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/07/31/how-to-install-mysql-server-5-6-on-centos-7-rhel-7/)